# I am finding that .rstrip('.csv') is stripping a 'c' I don't want it to strip - how to prevent this?

Tags: python, strip

If I have a string (filename) that is something on the order of `xyc.csv`, and this name is stored as `stringA`, I found that:

```
stringB = stringA.rstrip('.csv')
```

Ends up causing `stringB` to have a value of `xy`, when it should have a value of `xyc`. Or at least I think it should.

Has anyone else noticed this? How do I make this stop?

Comment: I don't think it will strip the upper case 'C' though. It will strip any lower case 'c', up to a point where it doesn't find any character (from the right) that isn't in ".csv": `rstrip` and equivalents look at any *individual* character in the argument string given.

Comment: You could also consider `os.path.splitext`.

Comment: Its because I made the string (file name) uppercase when I shouldn't have.

Comment: @traggatmot: this is why we don't do "something on the order of" but give a  [mcve].. ;-)

Comment: I tried - I just messed up in hurrying.  I tried with it two ways (all with caps, and all without caps), and messed up in writing the question.  Knowing what to do knows not always mean you will successfully do it.  Mistakes will always be made.

Comment: I should mention that the duplicate target question has the [same Problem Y, but a different Problem X](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (with its own unique correct solution).

Answer (score 4):

`rstrip` removes all characters that are present in the passed string, until it hits a character not in the passed string.

```
>>> 'abcxyzxyz'.rstrip('xyz')
'abc'
```

If you want to remove a file extension, I'd recommend `os.path.splitext()`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext(r'C:\Users\John Doe\file.txt')
('C:\\Users\\John Doe\\file', '.txt')
>>> os.path.splitext(r'C:\Users\John Doe\file.txt')[0]
'C:\\Users\\John Doe\\file'
```

Answer (score 0):

`rstrip` means "remove all characters from the end that match any of the ones in this string." It does not mean "remove this string from the end" as you assume.

You will have to check if the string ends in .csv and then remove 4 characters if it does.

Answer (score -1):

Use a regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\\.csv$', '', 'XYZ.csv')
'XYZ'
```

`rstrip` isn't appropriate for this task, because it treats the string as an array of individual characters, and removes as many of those characters as it can in whatever order they occur.

For filenames in particular there's an alternate solution: the `os.path` module manipulates filenames and can easily remove an extension no matter what it is.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext('XYZ.csv')[0]
'XYZ'
```

Comment: `re.sub('\\.csv', '', 'XYZ.csv.txt')` likely doesn't do what is wanted. Ditto with `str.replace()`. They are not equivalent to the `rstrip` variant the OP is thinking of.

Comment: @Evert, thanks very much. I was intending to put a `$` on the end of the pattern string but forgot, now it's fixed.